# How to join 2 json files by one key

Tags: jq

jsonfile1

```
[
    [
        "i-pfasdqaertcbidlkl",
        "Some_Task",
        "t2.small",
        "running",
        "4.3.2.1",
        "Malaysia_db",
        "2018-04-10T13:56:50.000Z",
        "db",
        null,
        "1.2.3.4",
        null,
        null
    ]
]
```

jsonfile2

```
[
    "i-pfasdqaertcbidlkl",
    false
]
```

I want to join both files by `i-pfasdqaertcbidlkl`

Output Needed

```
[
    [
        "i-pfasdqaertcbidlkl",
        "Some_Task",
        "t2.small",
        "running",
        "4.3.2.1",
        "Malaysia_db",
        "2018-04-10T13:56:50.000Z",
        "db",
        null,
        "1.2.3.4",
        null,
        null,
        false
    ]
]
```

Comment: Could there be _other_ subarrays in the first file whose first element is not `i-pfasdqaertcbidlkl`? May there be several ones that _are_ the same?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, sorry for responding too late to your comments

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry, I just noticed, I the heading I gave to my question was wrong, I just need a join.